# Separating git reposistory/history into two seperate branches based on files touched

Tags: git

Let's say I have a git repo laid out like the following.

branch master

```
./.gitignore
./README
./foo/
./foo/magic.py
./foo/document.txt
./bar/
./bar/baxy.c
./herp/
./herp/derp.h
```

There are a bunch of commits, modifying or creating those files.
What if I wanted to split off the history (not sharing the first initial commit isn't required, but it's fine if they do), into two branches (assuming that branches are the best way to do this) into

branch A

```
./.gitignore
./foo/
./foo/magic.py
./foo/document.txt
```

branch B

```
./.gitignore
./README
./bar/
./bar/baxy.c
./herp/
./herp/derp.h
```

There is no guarantee that the commits didn't touch both `foo/magic.py` and `herp/derp.h` in the same commit for example. The branches should have all the history of the commits affecting those files, commits that affected multiple files (across the history split) can be broken up.

What/how should I do? (I have considered just shrugging, copying the files, and saying screw the history, but that seems like a cop out.)

EDIT:

Pretty sure that `git filter-branch` holds the key here, but never worked with it before, gonna do some reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite a complete solution, but `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter foo` would rewrite the repository to have a new root of ./foo, so it'd look like

```
./magic.py
./document.txt
```

with the accompanying history of those commits.

It's certainly close enough to what I wanted, a .gitignore file's history isn't essential, and can easy be retroactively inserted as the first commit, given that we're breaking SHA1 hash compatibility anyway.